# Modify dependent variable in stiff solver (vode)

Tags: fortran, numerical, ode, netlib

I am using the [dvode](http://www.netlib.org/ode/vode.f) ODE solver from [netlib](http://www.netlib.org) to solve a stiff sparse system (the application is atmospheric chemistry). On the first call of the subroutine `dvode` completes a set of initialisation tasks, and takes the array of initial value of the dependent variable `y` as input. In subsequent calls, the routine performs the actual integration and the array `y` is used as output only.

For various reasons, I need to modify one element of the dependent array `y` during the integration. As `y` is used as output for all but the first call to `dvode`, modifications to the input values of `y` are ignored. It appears the relevant data are stored in a workspace array.

Is there any way to coerce `dvode` to let me change the value of the dependent array during the integration? I don't want to mess with the internals of the solver, and if possible I want to avoid altering the workspace arrays, since there may be all kinds of dependencies that will be difficult to foresee. I have tried alternating between initialisation and integration calls, but this makes things *much* slower.

If there is no clear solution, I would also consider trying another (Fortran-compatible) solver for stiff, highly non-linear ODEs.

Comment: This will be difficult to solve. The solver probably doesn't support this kind of usage. There are many other solvers, but SO is not the right place to ask for them. Try to look at http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/odepack/odepack_home.html or http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Ordinary-Differential-Equations.html

Comment: Thanks Valdimir. As far as I can see, the principle (i.e. the state vector being output-only for all calls except the first) applies in the other ODEPACK solvers. I will investigate the GSL solvers.